# running code example from Mysql website causes std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I downloaded the mysql C++ connector package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/. I wrote a simple program that used it. Following is the code. this code is actually part of example code at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

```
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
int main(void)
{
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");

  delete con;

  return 0;
}
```

Running it produced following error message:

```
[frank@arch mysql-connector-c++]$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

why didn't it work?

Comment: Try this: `driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html)

Comment: I tried it,  it produced the same error. By the way, it's actually sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance()

Comment: @frank Did you get a solution to this problem?